# how to upload a certificate in VM of azure cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, pfx

**This line is creating problem as it requires the Cert to be present in the machine in which it is currently executing..**

`topologyConfigurationManager = new TopologyConfigurationManager(new Uri("https://int2.metrics.nsatc.net"), GenevaCertThumbprint, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));`

I have gone through this link [deploying-application-certificates-to-the-cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure#deploying-application-certificates-to-the-cluster)

but still i am not able to get how to upload certificate in VM(nodes) of azure cluster.Can some one give me detailed step of where to upload the cert(.pfx file).

Comment: Upload to azure keyvault and modify your cluster ARM template and deploy

Comment: @Mardoxx if I add client side cert ("Admin-client") will it work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the answer::
Login to the Node of Remote cluster using following command in cmd:`mstsc /v:mycluster.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3389`

Where "*mycluster.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com*" is cluster name.After logging in Install certifcates Manually.

*3389-is first node 3390-second node and so on.*

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem few days ago, i was needing to change to a new certificate because the old has expired, and i solved it by deploying the azure resource template for service fabric again, which means that i'd basically recreated the all environment.

In the template i've only changed the certificate link and the thumbprint.

Comment: If done correctly it should only perform operations on modified values. In this case each VM should be provisioned with the new certificate.